# Why we need guava in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, guava

I created selenium web driver project with maven. 
I read somewhere we need to add guava dependency.

Can anybody why we need guava dependency with selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best information I can arrange.

**Summarize Answer:**

> **Selenium** uses **Guava** libraries for `Function and Predicates`.

**Reference for above quote (Page-126) :**

[https://books.google.de/books?id=PMNiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=selenium+and+guava&source=bl&ots=hxRq2Dq61Y&sig=ACfU3U3ro_HhI4cpejvSSSEvWYZMF99l9g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO7oOP6PHmAhUCCewKHfnJDSs4ChDoATABegQIChAB#v=onepage&q&f=false](https://books.google.de/books?id=PMNiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=selenium%20and%20guava&source=bl&ots=hxRq2Dq61Y&sig=ACfU3U3ro_HhI4cpejvSSSEvWYZMF99l9g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO7oOP6PHmAhUCCewKHfnJDSs4ChDoATABegQIChAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**Brief about Function and Predicates with example used in Selenium:**

Guava provides two basic "functional" interfaces:

- **Function**, which has the single method B apply(A input).
  Instances of Function are generally expected to be referentially
  transparent -- no side effects -- and to be consistent with equals,
  that is, a.equals(b) implies that
  function.apply(a).equals(function.apply(b))

**Example:**

```
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        }
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds-in-java) you can also check. Mainly used in Selenium Waits (except implicit).

- **Predicate**, which has the single method boolean apply(T input).
  Instances of Predicate are generally expected to be side-effect-free
  and consistent with equals.

**Example:**

[selenium filter with Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174546/selenium-filter-with-predicate)

[here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained) you can find details of `Function and Predicates` on `Guava` official Documentation

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Guava

[Guava](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guava/index.htm) is an open source, Java-based library developed by Google. It facilitates developers and test automation engineers in adapting best coding practices and helps reduce coding errors. It provides utility methods for collections, caching, primitives support, concurrency, common annotations, string processing, I/O, and validations.

---

### Maven Dependency

As of *Selenium v3.141.59* clients the *Maven Dependency* is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Incompatible library version selenium / guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284776/incompatible-library-version-selenium-guava/50287063#50287063)
- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList; with Selenium 3.5.3 Chrome 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634492/org-openqa-selenium-remote-service-driverservicebuilder-createargslcom-google/57658406#57658406)
- [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V with IE and Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856558/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargument/51872398#51872398)
- [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014053/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-p/52034052#52034052)